# Shading issue when adding Subdivision Modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, faces

Firt things first, needless to say that I'm still a newbie haha.

I've been learning how to model with extruding vertex and faces, instead of starting from a cube.

Everything went pretty well until I decided to add a Subdivision Surface modifier to smooth everything and I found this(Also happens when I right click and check shade smooth):

[image]

Also I let you see the X-Ray version, which made worry:

[image]

So thanks in advance and any help would be appreciated :3

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stack Exchange. Please show **and** tell. A little more information about what you mean would be really helpful. Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) to learn how you could help us to give good answers.

Answer (score 3):

Looks originally like "Normal" problem. this post will give you an idea about it. it happens a lot when models are extruded.

[Blender How to Recalculate Normals](https://all3dp.com/2/blender-recalculate-normals-simply-explained/)

Comment: Thank you mate :D I'll save this for future references

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by deleting the faces and adding them again.

Comment: Hey :). In the future, you can just recalculate face orientation. Some faces are visibly flipped in your x-ray view. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Oh thank you :) I'll keep that in mind for future cases hehe